# Django query timestamp seems to behave differently

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime, filter, utc

I would like to query some data from a postgres database where we store some values. However it seems that when I do this in Django with a python script that is called from views.py the data is shifted one hour.

**Example:**

Query from script file:

```html
sensorData = SensorDataAvgFirstTwoMonths.objects.filter(timestamp__gte='2019-11-06 07:50:00',
                                                          timestamp__lte='2019-11-06 08:00:00',
                                                          machine_id=4, 
                                                          type_id=25).order_by('timestamp');
  print(sensorData)
  for d in sensorData:
      print(d.timestamp)
      print(d.value)
```

This result in the following print:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwlJL.png)

Now, if I query data directly from the terminal then I have to shift one hour to get the same result (except for the fact that the quires are slightly different).
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVOH.png)

The time in the database is in UTC time. I would expect that I do not need to shift time one hour in the Django query to get the same result. But I guess that the query in Django take some timezone into account but how can I get the same result when setting the date and time exactly the same in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I realized that in global_settings.py the parameter TIME_ZONE set  to Stockholm/Europe, when I changed this to UTC the same query gave the same result.